# Orchestration of Redshift stored procedures using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I have multiple Redshift stored procedures (~15), some are dependent on the previous run stored procedures while some can run asynchronously.

I need to orchestrate this with proper failure handling in case any successor stored procedure fails then I can run that particular one.

I tried orchestrating this using AWS Eventbridge but in that, I found many limitations. Like triggering any specific stored procedure. Using Eventbridge rules 5 targets to run both combination sync and async
[image]

**Is there any way to run my stored procedures in AWS Glue using custom canvas, to construct orchestration. Putting one stored procedue in one block**
[image]

**How to make redshift connection in the flow diagram so that my stored procedure will be executed in my redshift cluster?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Glue (I doubt it) but this is a great case for Step Functions.  Lots of blogs about how to set up a serverless data orchestration process using Step Functions with proper error / exception handling.  A place to start - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-multiple-etl-jobs-using-aws-step-functions-and-aws-lambda/